# How to validate zipcode in textfield of CF7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7, add-filter

I have a textfield in CF7 which I want to validate if the users input is 4 digits and 2 characters, like: 1234AB (with no spaces and with capital letters).

This is what I have already, but it doesn't work:

```
function custom_postcode_validation_filter($result,$tag){

    $name = $tag->name;

    if($name == 'ba-postcode'){

        $bapostcode = $_POST['ba-postcode'];

        if($bapostcode != '') {

            if(!preg_match('/^([0-9]{4})\\([^a-Z]{2})$/', $bapostcode)) {

                $result->invalidate( $tag, "Vul alstublieft een geldige postcode in." );

            }

        }

    }

    return $result;
}   

add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_postcode_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'custom_postcode_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
```

I think it's probably something with this line:
`if(!preg_match('/^([0-9]{4})\\([^a-Z]{2})$/', $bapostcode)) {`.

So I updated the answer after getting some help. This is what I have now:

```
function custom_postcode_validation_filter($result,$tag){

    $name = $tag->name;

    if($name == 'ba-postcode'){

        $bapostcode = $_POST['ba-postcode'];

        if($bapostcode != '') {

            $regex = "/^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{2}$/i";

if(!preg_match( $regex, $bapostcode)) {
    $result->invalidate( $tag, "Vul alstublieft een geldige postcode in." );
}

    return $result;
}   

add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_postcode_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'custom_postcode_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
    }
 }
```

It's still not working. What am I missing?

Also I would like that if the user fills in the field without capital letters, the textfield transforms them automatically.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Your regular expression is saying 4 numbers then a backslash then not a-Z for the next two characters.

Comment: If you're trying to match 4 numbers then 2 letters, you'll want something like '/^([0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2})$/'

Comment: I tried that to, but it didn’t work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it done with this code:

```
function custom_postcode_validation_filter($result,$tag){

    $name = $tag->name;

    if($name == 'ba-postcode'){

        $bapostcode = $_POST['ba-postcode'];

        if($bapostcode != '') {

            if(!preg_match('/^([1-9]{1})([0-9]{3})([\s]{0,1})([a-zA-Z]{2})$/', $bapostcode)) {

                $result->invalidate( $tag, "Vul alstublieft een geldige postcode in." );

            }

        }

    }

    return $result;
}   

add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_postcode_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'custom_postcode_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex expression, I have used it in a Dutch site which shares a similar structure.

```
function custom_postcode_validation_filter( $result,$tag ){

    if( 'ba-postcode' == $tag->name ){

        // Get postcode field
        $bapostcode = isset( $_POST['postcode'] ) ? trim( $_POST['postcode'] ) : '';

        // Check postcode is set
        if($bapostcode != '') {

            // match postcodes 1234AB
            $regex = "/^[1-9][0-9]{3}(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{2}$/i";

            // validate postcode
            if( !preg_match( $regex, $bapostcode ) ) {
                $result->invalidate( $tag, "Vul alstublieft een geldige postcode in." );
            }

        }   
    }

    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_postcode_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'custom_postcode_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you. It’s for a Dutch website, so that’s why it’s similar :-). I changed this line `if(!preg_match('/^([0-9]{4})\\([^a-Z]{2})$/', $bapostcode)) {` for your code, but that doesn’t work unfortunately. It accepts every input I type in.

Comment: its working in my local instance, maybe you have another php error on the page?

Comment: I added the complete code to my original question. Maybe I look over something?

Comment: Try now, i refactored your code to closer match the documentation here: https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/ Also in your updated code example you had included the add_filters inside of the function, not sure if this was intentional

Comment: That wasn't intentional actually. Your new code doesn't work either. Can't figure out why. When I try your code it doesn't validate the whole form anyone. The console gave me this error: `[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (admin-ajax.php, line 0)` `https://www.domain.nl/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpcf7cf_validate_step`

Comment: Add WP_DEBUG_LOG true to your wp-config.php file, then check the debug.log file created in the wp-content folder

Comment: This is what the error log says: `FastCGI: server "/var/run/php74-cgi/php-cgi" stderr: thrown in /www/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/modules/text.php on line 129` and this is what's on that line: `$result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );`

Comment: I got it done to work! Please see my answer at the bottom. It now accepts `1234AB` and `1234ab`. I would only would like to also accept `1234 AB` and `1234 ab`. Any thoughts?